# On the continuity of functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

We have the following situation. Assume that $X$ a topological space, $u\in C(X)$ and $u\geq0$, then $U:=\{x\in X: u(x)>0\}$ is open in $X$. Moreover let $f\in C(U)$ and define for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the function $g_n$ on $X$ by $g_n(x)=\min\{f(x),n\cdot u(x)\}$ if $x\in U$ and $g_n(x)=0$ if $x\in X\setminus U$. The claim is that $g_n$ is continuous foe each $n$. Here C denote the space of continuous functions.

I think you can prove this by application of nets. Therefore assume $(x_a)_{a\in A}$ is a net in $X$ such that $x_a\rightarrow x$. We have to show that $g_n(x_a)\rightarrow g_n(x)$. This is clearly true if $x_a\in U$ for each $a\in A$ of if $x_a\in X\setminus U$ for each $a\in A$, but this has not to be the general case. How to prove this claim? Thank you very much.

Comment: What does $C$ denote?

Comment: Sorry, I think there miss some information.

Answer (score 1):

You need one more hypothesis: you must either assume that $f\ge 0$, or define

$$g_n(x)=\min\{|f(x)|,nu(x)\}$$

for $x\in U$. I’ll write this up using the latter assumption.

If $x\in U$, then there is an $a_0\in A$ such that $x_a\in U$ whenever $a\succeq a_0$, and if $x\in X\setminus\operatorname{cl}U$, there is an $a_0\in A$ such that $x_a\in X\setminus\operatorname{cl}U$ whenever $a\succeq a_0$; in both cases it’s clear that $g_n(x_a)\to g_n(x)$. Thus, we may assume that $x\in(\operatorname{cl}U)\setminus U$. Then $g_n(x)=0$, and we must show that $g_n(x_a)\to 0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$; $u(x)=0$, so $x$ has an open nbhd $V$ such that $0\le u(y)<\frac{\epsilon}n$ for all $y\in V$. Fix $a_0\in A$ such that $x_a\in V$ whenever $a\succeq a_0$; then for each $a\succeq a_0$ we have

$$g_n(x_a)=\begin{cases}
\min\{|f(x_a)|,nu(x_a)\}\le nu(x_a)<\epsilon,&\text{if }x_a\in U\\
0<\epsilon,&\text{if }x\in X\setminus U\;,
\end{cases}$$

so $g_n(x_a)\to 0$, as desired.